# set date format for knitr document

Tags: r, date, format, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way to set a global option (either through options() or knitr::opts_chunk$set() or something else) to set all dates in a knitr/Rmd document to be formatted in a particular style. So instead of having to write `format(DATE, '%d %m %Y')` each time I have a date I can just write `DATE` and have the formatting done automagically?

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/update-date.html Check this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html) you could achieve your desired resulting via a custom `knit_print` method. To add some flexibility you could add the date format as a parameter in the YAML header which e.g. allows to render the document with different date formats.

````
---
title: Custom knit_print for Dates
output: html_document
params:
  date_format: '%d %m %Y'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
knit_print.Date = function(x, ...) {
  format(x, params$date_format)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "Date", knit_print.Date,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)

```

```{r}
DATE <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
```

`r as.Date(Sys.Date())`
````

[image]

Comment: I was hoping that there might be something a bit prettier than that, but it will do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to my question is to use flextable for table output and set

```
set_flextable_defaults(
   fmt_date = '%d-%m-%Y',
   fmt_datetime = '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

in the setup chunk. This obviously doesn't work for dates that are not displayed in tables, but still, it goes most of the way to solving my original problem.